# Jquery Ajax response in rails is returning undefined data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to use ajax so only a partial reloads and not the entire website, but the data is returning undefined. Am I doing something incorrect? Here's the code:

/* form.js */

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#stock-lookup-form').on('ajax:complete', (e, data, status) => {
    /*$('#results').html(data.responseText)*/
    console.log(data) /* --> this returns undefined*/
  }) 
})
```

/* stocks_controller.rb */

```rb
class StocksController < ApplicationController
  def search
    if params[:stock].present?
      @stock = Stock.new_from_lookup(params[:stock])
      if @stock
        render partial: 'users/result'
      else
        flash[:danger] = "You have entered an incorrect symbol"
        redirect_to my_portfolio_path
      end
    else 
      flash[:danger] = "You have entered an empty search string"
      redirect_to my_portfolio_path
    end
  end
end
```

/* result.html.erb partial */

```html
<%if @stock%>
  <div class="well results-block">
    <strong>Symbol: </strong><%=@stock.ticker%>
    <strong>Name: </strong><%=@stock.name%>
    <strong>Last price: </strong><%=@stock.last_price%>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

/* my_portfolio.html.erb (where the form is located) */

```html
<h1>My portfolio</h1>

<h3>Search for stocks</h3>
<div id="stock-lookup">
  <%=form_tag search_stocks_path, remote: true, method: :get, id: 'stock-lookup-form' do%>
    <div class="form-group row no-padding text-center col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <%=text_field_tag :stock, params[:stock], placeholder:'Stock ticker symbol', autofocus:true, class:'form-control search-box input-lg'%>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <%=button_tag(type: :submit, class:'btn btn-lg btn-success', id:'search-btn') do%>
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Look up a stock
        <%end%>
      </div>
    </div>
  <%end%>
</div>
<div id="results">
  <%=render 'users/result'%>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> [The] Signature of calls to UJS's event handlers has changed. Unlike the version with jQuery, all custom events return only one parameter: event. In this parameter, there is an additional attribute detail which contains an array of extra parameters.
> https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#rails-ujs-event-handlers

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#stock-lookup-form').on('ajax:complete', (event) => {
    const [data, status, xhr] = event.detail;
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Oh I did not know that, thank you very much! I'll try it asap